# How to change the batch size of pcp in linux kernel?

Tags: linux, configuration, memory, linux-kernel

I increased the [pcp->high](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14/source/include/linux/mmzone.h#L363) via `echo 8 > /proc/sys/vm/percpu_pagelist_fraction` command, but the pcp->batch value still remains at 63.

```
vm stats threshold: 125
cpu: 383
          count: 103931
          high:  193513
          batch: 63
```

Is there a way to increase the pcp->batch value?
I'm using Linux kernel 5.14.